# Snowflake schema: fact table with foreign key to a sub dimension?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, ssas, data-modeling, data-warehouse

Using the snowflake schema image from wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Snowflake-schema-example.png

Would it ever make sense to have a "Brand_Id" foreign key in Fact_Sales as you do in Dim_Product? There is a many-to-one relationship of sales/brands just like sales/products or products/brands, so is there any logical reason not to? You may want to join directly to the Dim_Brand table.

I'm probably not seeing something obvious.

Answer (score 2):

The type of relationship you're looking at is a [has-a](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Has-a) relationship.

A product has a brand.  A sale has a product; it's the thing that was sold.  But a sale does not have a brand.  Or, a better way of saying this, you cannot sell a brand. (don't read too far into that one...)

So, no, you wouldn't want to add brand to sales.

Comment: Thanks.  So sales relates directly to products but indirectly to brand.  So, in regard to a snowflake schema, would there ever be a situation where you'd want a FK to that 2nd-level dimension?  What about a situation where the dimensions (and fact) roll up levels?  For example, replace product->store->brand with task->phase->project (i.e. "Project" is made up of "phases" which are made up of "tasks".)  Would that same logic apply or would this be a case where you may want to have a ProjectID in FactTask?

Comment: What you're proposing is a star schema (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema).  You can do this, since these objects are related.  You'll gain a bit of a performance increase, but you end up with a bit of a square-peg-round-hole issue.  You're manipulating the data to fit your need, rather than altering your schema to fit your data.  Short answer: it can go either way, but you'll have to do the research to decide what's best for your needs.

Comment: Doh.  Good point, Norla.  Rather than a snowflake schema with a FK to a subdimension, it is clearly easier to state it as a star schema with an FK between dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

If you are working in a dimensional model (the Star/Snowflake schema note in your question makes be think you are), then adding the BRAND_ID to the sales fact makes sense from a performance perspective, if the questions that the business is trying to answer are "what were the sales for brand X across all products in this time frame".

It also may be useful if the product dimension is a Type 1 SCD, and a product changes brands. You may want to preserve the prior sales as being of the "old" brand.

Keep in mind you are *not* doing entity - relationship modeling when you build a star/snowflake reporting schema. Questions of is-a or has-a aren't pertinent to a dimensional model.

Answer (score 0):

I think that would be nice as a way to cache the data... but in all honesty, your probably better off just relying on the links as they are.

The reasoning is that you already have that definition of what that table does, store sales. To add in what brand those products are that the store sold is going to muddy the 'topic' or 'theme' of that table, recording sales of a store.

Now if by some way you had a product that can be sold under different brands (heck if I know how a package can have split personalities...) then yea, it would make sense to a degree, but a more reasonable solution is to give each product it's own SKU code then.